# Is there any way to implement Ken Wheeler/Slick JS to my shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, shopify, slick.js

I'm using "Debut" as theme of my store in shopify. I would like to use Slick JS as image slide for my product gallery. I tried and it work! but the functionality of "selecting variants and showing it's image" is gone.

this is my code inside **product-template.liquid**:

```
<div class="adsurf_slickslide_container" role='toolbar'>
    {% assign index = 0 %}
    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      {% for image in product.images %}
          {% assign index = index | plus: 1 %}

            <span class="slide" data-index="{{ index }}" data-variant-img="{{ image.id }}">
              <img data-advar="{{ product.options_with_values | escape  }}" src="{{ image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            </span>

      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
      $('div.adsurf_slickslide_container').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true
      });

      $(document).on('change', 'select.single-option-selector', function(){
        var customVal = $(this).val();

        var hittedIndex = $('span img#' + customVal).data('index');
        console.log('span img[addata=' + customVal + ']');

        if(hittedIndex != undefined)
            $('div.adsurf_slickslide_container').slick('slickGoTo', hittedIndex);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Shopify debut theme loads  vendor.js  which included the jQuery already.

I can see you loaded jQuery again.  This is the issue i guess.

Remove this line

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

and your theme should work properly.

Kind Regards